# How to properly use this trigonometric identity?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I have to calculate the limit of:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(3x-\frac{\pi}{2})}{x}$$

And it obviously indetermines with $\frac{0}{0}$.

So I used trigonometric identities and converted it:

$$\cos(3x-\frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin(3x)$$

By using the $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-u)=\sin{u}$ identity, but I got stuck there, I still have that $0$ in the denominator; so I used wolfram alpha and it says that:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(3x)}{x} = 3$$

But I just can't figure out why, I haven't been able to find any identity or rule so that I can remove that $x$.

What is the right procedure to follow from there? Did I at least apply that identity correctly?

Comment: Using L'Hopitals rule on your limit also works, if you have that tool.

Comment: I haven't seen anything related to L'Hopital on my classes, so I can say I don't *have that tool*, but by seeing the answers I think it's the only way to go.

Comment: Using L'Hopital is the standard way to calculate the $\sin(x)/x$ limit. But there are ways other than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim**. $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(ax)}{ax} = 1\text{.}$$

Using L-Hospital,
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(ax)}{ax} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{a\cos(ax)}{a} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0}\cos(ax) = 1\text{.}$$

Similar to your problem, I've shown that 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(3x)}{3x} = 1\text{.}$$
Thus
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(3x)}{3x} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0}\left[\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{\sin(3x)}{x}\right] = \dfrac{1}{3}\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\left[\dfrac{\sin(3x)}{x}\right] = 1\text{.}$$
Multiply both sides by $3$, and you get
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\left[\dfrac{\sin(3x)}{x}\right] = 3\text{.} $$

Comment: Normally the limit $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$ is developed before L-Hospital, which you can reduce your first limit to by the substitution $t=ax$.

Comment: @Peter - That would be another way, since as $x \to 0$, $ax \to 0$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

You applied the first identity correctly. There is an identity $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$. Multiply your expression by $\frac{3}{3}$ to obtain the limit $3$.

Comment: So, are you saying that $sin(3x)=3sin(x)$? So I can eliminate that $x$ with the $sin(x)$ and I'm only left with the $3$?

Comment: @arielnmz Not quite. See the other answers for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(3x-\frac{\pi}{2})}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} 3.\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x}=3$$
Note that: $$cos(3x-\pi/2)=\cos(\pi/2-3x)=\sin 3x$$